# Trying to pickle object instance throws pickling error

Tags: python, pickle

I am trying to pickle class instance, referring to http://stefaanlippens.net/python-pickling-and-dealing-with-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-thing.html
However gives me

try.py

```
import pickle

class abc(object):
      def __init__(self):
         self.a = 10
      def save(self):
         pickle.dump(self,open("try.pkl","wb"))
if __name__ == '__main__':
      a = abc()
      abc.__module__ = "try"
      a.save()

pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'try.abc'>: it's not the same object as try.abc
```

Am I making a mistake here ?
Is there a different solution to pickle object for stand alone purpose

Comment: Why are you screwing with `abc.__module__`?

Comment: The article you're looking at relies on an awkward hack that doesn't work any more. Don't screw with `__module__`; import `try` and use `try.abc` instead of `abc` (and curse Python's awkward `__main__` system).

Comment: @user2357112 Yes I too wonder that that hack does not work any more. However my problem is, I need a stand alone way to pickle class object and it's instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you take away your `abc.__module__ = "try"` everything works fine.

```
import pickle

class abc(object):
      def __init__(self):
         self.a = 10
      def save(self):
         pickle.dump(self,open("try.pkl","wb"))
if __name__ == '__main__':
      a = abc()
      a.save()

      # proof it worked
      with open('try.pkl','rb') as pkl_file:
          b = pickle.load(pkl_file)
      print(b.a)
```

I've added code at the end to reload the data and print it to show it was successful.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for reply, yes it would work, however when you load try.pkl without importing try.py in a separate file, it won't load and will throw attribute error. – Dwipam Katariya

Comment: This would seem a given, if you don't import the class you can't create an instance of it which is what you are essentially doing when you create it from a pickle. What's the architectural/packaging hurdle preventing importing the class?